# Winter Bash, aka: Am I the only one who's missing the hats here?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I know this site only opened today, so isn't officially part of the Winter Bash, but is anyone else missing the hats? Should we petition [Abby T. Miller](http://stackexchange.com/users/463168/abby-t-miller) to add hats to this site?

Comment: This is apparently a no-go: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212206/winter-bash-opt-in-fails-on-private-beta-sites.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We asked the moderators and never heard back.  If it's any consolation, [Aviation was opted out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212206/winter-bash-opt-in-fails-on-private-beta-sites#comment682807_212207) too.

But seriously, brand new sites don't get hats because it might effect participation in unpredictable ways.  We'd like people in the earliest stages to be focused on laying the groundwork for the site going public and not trying to obtain virtual headgear.  Sorry to disappoint.  I miss my menorah here too.

Comment: well, next year we will be proudly wear our hat :-)